# what does p in "3-CNF-SAT ≤p SUBSET-SUMS" mean?

Tags: notation, algorithms, satisfiability

I come across this notation [image]

from book "[Introduction to Algorithm, CLRS](https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf)", page 1097, but have no idea why p is subscript

Another source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8Kt9IBZ8FU

Comment: "polynomial time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p$ stands for polynomial, and $A \leq_p B$ means "$A$ is polynomially reducible to $B$" - we have a polynomial algorithm that given some word $x$ outputs other word $y$ s.t. $x \in A \iff y \in B$ (the idea is if $A \leq_p B$ then solving $A$ is not harder than solving $B$). See "Reducibility" on page 1067 in the book you linked.